# Generic Abstract Enum

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on state machine for my Unity experimenting and I want to create system that would be responsible for state of individual objects.

My vision is this:

StateManager - Class responsible for Transforming states etc.

StateCollection - Abstract class in which derived clases would hold all instances of States for the object.

Enum - I want to use enums to select which state should be active now.

My Implementation looks like this:

```
public class StateManager<T,enumT> where T : StateCollection, new() where enumT : Enum
{

  private T states = new T();
  public T States 
  {
      get { return states;}
  }

  public void TransformState(enumT newState)
  {
    //some code
  }
}

public abstract class StateCollection
{

  public GameObject Object { get; set; }
  public abstract State GetState<enumT>(enumT enumState);
}

public class PlayerStatesCollection<enumT> : StateCollection
{

  private PlayerIdleState Idle = new PlayerIdleState();
  private PlayerShootState Shoot = new PlayerShootState();
  private PlayerMoveState Move = new PlayerMoveState();
  private PlayerDeadState Dead = new PlayerDeadState();



  public override State GetState(enumT enumState)
  {

    switch (enumState)
    {
        case PlayerStates.Idle:
            return Idle;
        case PlayerStates.Move:
            return Move;
        case PlayerStates.Shoot:
            return Shoot;
        case PlayerStates.Dead:
            return Dead;
        default:
            throw new System.Exception("Invalid State. #002");
    }
  }

}

public enum PlayerStates
{
  Idle,
  Shoot,
  Move,
  Dead
}
```

Now when I create Instance of StateManager I must write something like this:

```
public StateManager<PlayerStatesCollection<PlayerStates>, PlayerStates> StavManager = new StateManager<PlayerStatesCollection<PlayerStates>, PlayerStates>();
```

now I am not kinda happy with this, how it looks.. The generic parameter has twice "PlayerStates" which is unnecessary because it always be the same and I have not figured out how to do simply with "just"

```
StateManager<PlayerStatesCollection,PlayerStates>
```

If I create for example EnemyStatesCollection, it will be derived from StateCollection and have its own enum EnemyStates. and when I work with StateManager to transform state I want to be able to use its own enum, which will be defined when StateManager is created.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning for making `PlayerStatesCollection` generic? I don't see why it should be generic.